# Are there any references to A\The "Black Sword" in official Attack on Titan source material?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In 2007 Epic released a song entitled [Crimson Bow and Arrow](https://genius.com/Epica-crimson-bow-and-arrow-lyrics) as part of their EP [Epic Vs Attack on Titan](https://genius.com/albums/Epica/Epica-vs-attack-on-titan-songs-ep)

The tracks on the EP all relate to, or are inspired by, different aspects of the Attack on Titan Anime\Manga, this particular song included the line:

> The boy will pick up the black sword

The song relates to Erin and his attitude to fighting the Titans, but I'm unaware of there being a literal Black Sword in canon. does this refer to the swords used by the scouts, or is it something figurative, or did I just lose something in translation?

Comment: It might just be an euphemism to refer to a bloodened sword. As the blood coagulates and oxidizes it turns a deep dark red color that's almos blackish, so a blood-stained sword that keeps being used without proper cleaning will turn black over time.The swords the Scouts use are intended to be used and discarded, they are not legendary swords, just as them are not invincible heroes, but sacrifices necessary for the freedom of mankind, as such, picking up the black sword is not picking a the literal black sword, but the will of the Scouts lives and their blood stained discarded swords.